# Matching a single line comment in QSyntaxHighlighter with QRegularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, character-encoding

I'm trying to highlight single-line comments in VBScript using QSyntaxHighlighter in Qt 5.14.2. All example code I was able to find uses QRegExp instead of QRegularExpression, where a simple pattern like `'[^\n]*` or `'.*$` seems to do the job.
However, this doesn't work with QRegularExpression (which is required by QSyntaxHighlighter) and both of these match everything following `'` **including** all newlines. What am I doing wrong?

Relevant code:

```
auto regexOptions = QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption;
HighlightingRule rule;
rule.pattern = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("'[^\n]*"), regexOptions);
rule.format = format_SinglelineComment;
highlightingRules.append(rule);
```

**Update:** Turns out this is not an issue with regex, but rather with encoding. When I retrieve the TextEdit contents via `->toPlainText().toStdString()`, I get a properly formatted string with `\n` for line breaks. If I take the text being passed to `highlightBlock` and do `.toStdString()` on it, I get `â€¨` instead of `\n`, indicating an encoding issue. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: In a regex a newline is normally written as '$' so I would guess this should do it: "'.*$"

Comment: I tried using '.*$ but that also did not work. It seems that the $ character does absolutely nothing in the matching...

Comment: `QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption` is not necessary here as there are no caseful letters in the pattern. `[^\n]` is not necessary, `.` will do as in a PCRE regex `.` does not match line breaks. Use `rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("'.*")`

Comment: The `CaseInsensitiveOption` is there for the other matches (keywords, etc). Using `'.*` still matches past the end of the line, so this didn't help either.